# Tweepy - Create tweet

Tags: python, twitter, bots, tweepy

I'm trying to create a twitter bot that would tweet a randomly selected text within a list.

When I use the `Client.create_tweet(text='test')` function, I get a message saying that I'm missing a required positional argument 'self'. From what I understand, this type of error is what you get when you don't initialized a function but those are predefined functions within Tweepy. I've imported access token and secret as well as api secret and key under, of course, `import tweepy`.

Am I missing something? What is the `self` that I should be including as parameter?

Comment: `Client` is a class. You need to create an instance of the class first `api = Client(…arguments go here…)`. Then you can call `api.create_tweet()`.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, here's a simple way to create a tweet with tweepy

to start you need to create the Client and insert your self keys:

```
import tweepy

api=tweepy.Client(
    bearer_token='',
    consumer_key='',
    consumer_secret='',
    access_token='',
    access_token_secret='', 
)
```

after that you can use try pay catch errors if you have:

```
try:
    tweet=api.create_tweet(text='test',)
    print(tweet)

except Exception as error:
    print(error)
```

finally, now you can run the py file

Comment: Please don't catch `Exception`, that breaks functionality like Ctrl-C. Instead, only catch the _specific_ exceptions you expect that code to throw